# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax, Can't identity the issue

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE team (
tid int primary key NOT NULL auto_increment,
name varchar(100),
captain int references student(sid),
gtype varchar(20),
leaguetype varchar(100),
divisiontype varchar(100),
pool int not null
);
```

Having trouble entering data into this table... coming back with the error in the subject title:

```
INSERT INTO team 
VALUES 
    (1, ’Bears’,1,’tennis’,’Competitive’,’1’,1), 
    (2, ’Gazelles’, 2, ‘tenis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 2), 
    (3, ‘Ducks’, 3, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 2), 
    (4, ‘Panthers’, 4, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 3), 
    (5, ‘Hawks’, 5, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 3), 
    (6, ‘Pirates’, 6, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 4), 
    (7, ‘Asians’, 7, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 4)
```

More specifically, this is what it returns

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '??Bears’,1,’tennis’,’Competitive’,’1’,1), (2,
>   ’Gazelles’, 2, ?' at line 2

Please advise!

Comment: You'll need to post the entire INSERT query if you want help.

Comment: Unable to answer as we cant see the insert query.

Comment: INSERT INTO team VALUES 
 (1, ’Bears’,1,’tennis’,’Competitive’,’1’,1),
 (2, ’Gazelles’, 2, ‘tenis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 2),
 (3, ‘Ducks’, 3, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 2),
 (4, ‘Panthers’, 4, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 3),
 (5, ‘Hawks’, 5, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 3),
 (6, ‘Pirates’, 6, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 4),
 (7, ‘Asians’, 7, ‘tennis’, ‘Competitive’, ‘1’, 4),

This is a portion of it~ thanks.

Comment: How can this be *both* MySQL and Sql Server?

Comment: You `INSERT` query doesn't match the error message. What are those question marks before `Bears`? I'm guessing it's some unicode characters and your table charset isn't set up correctly

Comment: The question marks came back in the error message, we've tried to reformat the way the information is represented, but it seems to come back with the same output.

Comment: Did you write the query in MS Word or something? Try replacing `’` with simple `'`

Answer (score 1):

Your enclosing ticks are tipographic ticks: `’`. You need to use the simple ASCII tick: `'` or quotation marks `"` to enclose strings.

Comment: Yes, 'single quotes' around the string trying to be inserted